# Difference Between Limited Edition and Standard Edition

Tags: merchandise, boku-wa-tomodachi-ga-sukunai

I am looking into buying some anime. But when I go on Amazon, there is a Standard and Limited edition for certain shows. But both say they contain 4 discs, though. I watch unboxings on YouTube for the certain series (like Haganai and Haganai: NEXT) and there doesn't seem to be any difference between the two besides a thicker box (which looks cooler on a shelf). Can someone explain this to me? Links, pictures, and examples would be great, thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, [Haganai](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/boku-wa-tomodachi-ga-sukunai) and [Haganai:NEXT](http://www.anime-planet.com/anime/boku-wa-tomodachi-ga-sukunai-next) are two different season of same series. Haganai:NEXT is a sequel of Haganai

Answer (score 1):

There is normally an obvious difference between Limited and Started Edition anime normally defined by the content they come with, the actual episodes however aren't different.

Limited Editions of Code Geass Lelouch of the Rebellion R2 and Tales of the Abyss came with Manga and the [first volume of Galaxy Angel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00018D5PI) on Amazon came with figures, pencil boards and a book.

On RightStuf the first volume of My-Z-HiME came in a special box, not like the one where you have the spins of the disk cases sticking out, this had a lid and also on one side it had the cast printed on a sheet of plastic and was positioned slightly in front of an image of the academy while the other side had Arika's jewel, there's one of it on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000PY30ZS). the Zwei OVA came with a shirt and there's one on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001EL6EAO) (images say it also comes with Pencil boards, i haven't opened by box yet and i missed that note on the box about what was inside)

Puella Magi Maodka Magica on Madman the only bonus was with Volume 1 and was a box to put the other 2 Volumes in, on RightStuf you got the Soundtrack, Cards, Art Book, all glittery and shiny, also there's 2 more Limited Edition Volumes while Madman never went further than a box.

Fate/Zero subbed on RightStuf original came with a Translation book on developer interviews which was missing in the Dubbed Limited Edition.

Sword Art Online on RightStuf, along with the soundtracks, came with limited edition Weiss Schwarz cards. i also remember getting a card in each volume of Fate/Zero dubbed but i can't remember if i did with the subbed (the subbed ones went into storage for safe keeping)

[NISA's Premium Editions](http://store.nisamerica.com/Anime/Premium) normally come in a large box with an art book inside however Love Live! School Idol Project has 2 Premium Editions. a standard one and the [Concert Set](http://store.nisamerica.com/Anime/Premium/Love-Live-School-Idol-Project-1st-Season-Premium-Concert-Set) which comes with the [OST](http://www.nisamerica.com/anime/lovelive/lovelive_OST.html).

also, NISA will oftern include a bonus item like [tear resistant posters](http://nisamerica.com/anime/fuse/fuse_bonus.jpg) ([Fusé: Memoirs of a Huntress](http://store.nisamerica.com/Anime/Premium/Fuse-Memoirs-of-a-Huntress-Premium-Bonus-Set)), [Student Council Armbands](http://nisamerica.com/anime/yuruyuri/yuruyuri2_bonus.jpg) ([YuruYuri Season 2](http://store.nisamerica.com/Anime/Premium/YURUYURI-Season-2-Premium-Bonus-Set)), [Ties](http://nisamerica.com/anime/HSboys/bonus.jpg) ([Daily Lives of High School Boys](http://store.nisamerica.com/Anime/Premium/Daily-Lives-of-High-School-Boys-Premium-Bonus-Set)) and RightStuf sells NISA stuff though i have yet to get a NISA Premium Edition from them since the PAL Lockout on NISA's store (Hanasaku Iroha the Movie ~ HOME SWEET HOME ~ is going t be the first). it should be noted these bonus items are in even limited supply than the Premium Edition themselves as Arakawa Under the Bridge used to come with a Kappa Mask of Chief however were out of stock by the time i started buying them

Generally a standard edition will just be a normal case with the disk inside, however Hanabee's stranded edition of [Nisemonogatari DVDs](http://hanabee.myshopify.com/products/nisemonogatari-part-2-dvd) are like little art books with the DVD inside while RightStuf Limited Editions includes cards, posters, soundtracks, of cause more expensive. it seems to be the same with other Monogatari releases between Hanabee and RightStuf since all the Monogatari DVDs i've brought from Hanabee has been the same book thing and i always notice a better limited edition on RightStuf

Also, Hanabee's Standard Edition of [Dusk Maiden on Amnesia](http://hanabee.myshopify.com/collections/everything/products/dusk-maiden-of-amnesia-dvd) came with the soundtrack though i still torrented it after because like most soundtracks ripped from disk, unless you have a net connection you don't get the Meta data (Album Name, Artist, Cover Art etc.)

So as you can see it all depends on the series and where you buy them. Limited/premium editions are normally worth buying because you get something in them you don't get with a standard edition, and great for collectors since they are limited for a reason, but you should always look up both and see exactly what is different and how much more your paying for the extra stuff

NOTE: i can't get any RightStuf Links due to it being blocked at work